# Sickest Tango?? Or Six to Ten Tango? Or Six to Ten to Go?

Tags: listening

I hope you are living good days every day.

I am sorry, could someone help me about the probable term on the title ( which I am trying to post on my blog ).

While I am listening to **[this](http://www.npr.org/player/v2/mediaPlayer.html?action=1&t=1&islist=false&id=468297948&m=468297949&live=1)**,

From 4:20～, I think she ( Samantha Power ) is saying

**>"And it is extremely important to have the diplomatic track, just as it was proved in Iran contexts. But it takes the sickest tango I guess in this case."**

I thought ( personally ) she is saying that. Or just am I wrong here?

Should I be corret about hearing this, what would that mean??

Or if I am wrong, what is she saying? Could someone help me.

I am sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She is saying:

> "But it takes **six to tango** I guess in this case."

A common similar phrase to get the meaning is:

> It takes two to tango.

See Wikipedia [***Takes two to tango (idiom)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29):

> It takes two to tango is a common idiomatic expression which suggests something in which more than one person or other entity are paired in an inextricably-related and active manner, occasionally with negative connotations.